# Vaadin Portlet maven dependency issue

Tags: vaadin, portlet

I'm reading the documentation to create my own portlets:
https://github.com/vaadin/flow-and-components-documentation/blob/master/documentation/portlet-support/portlet-02-creating-vaadin-portlets.asciidoc

The issue is that it seems that the maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
    <artifactId>vaadin-portlet</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

is not available anymore.

```
Failure to find com.vaadin:vaadin-portlet:jar:1.0.0 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Anyone knows how to solve that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: These docs' repo is archived. According to Maven central (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.vaadin/vaadin-portlet) 1.0.0.beta3 is the latest version.

Comment: There is also this starter project in case helpful: https://github.com/vaadin/base-starter-flow-portlet

Comment: Already tried with that one but the result was the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the artifact is released in Vaadin's own add-on repository, not in maven central. You need to add the following reposiotory to your pom.xml.

```
    <repository>
        <id>vaadin-addons</id>
        <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons/</url>
    </repository>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I downloaded a starter base project so it is already there, but not sure why it cannot be found

Comment: I accomplished to manually download the 1.0.0.beta3 and use it in the project but not sure if there is a lot of difference in comparisson with 1.0.0